# How to use nested FutureBuilders and make sure one future is called after another?

Tags: asynchronous, flutter, future

To avoid my `FutureBuilder` being called again and again (see [this](https://medium.com/saugo360/flutter-my-futurebuilder-keeps-firing-6e774830bc2)), I have the habbit of calling my futures in `initState` and it has always worked fine until I had to use nested ones.

Basically I want the second future to get called only after `connectionState` of 1st one becomes `done`. Any help?

Here is my code to explain further-

```
FutureBuilder(
  future: _future1,
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
    return snapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.done
        ? CircularProgressIndicator()
        : snapshot.data != 200
            ? SomeWidget()
            : FutureBuilder(
                future: _future2,
                builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                  return snapshot?.connectionState == ConnectionState.done
                      ? Text('')
                      : CircularProgressIndicator();
                });
  },
);
```

So basically, I don't want `_future2` to get called at all if the data received from `_future1` isn't 200. In other words, I want to decide whether `_future2`should be called or not on basis of result of `_future1`.

Comment: can you elaborate more. are you using `AsyncMemoizer` as described in the link? putting some code would help.

Comment: I have added code to explain more and no, I am not using `AsyncMemoizer`. Should I be doing that?

Comment: simply use one `FutureBuilder` - you dont need that two nested `FutureBuilder`s - instead you should use a `Future` which completes based on your two othe `Future`s

Comment: I didn't get you. Could you please explain more? (If possible, using code.)

Comment: see https://www.dartlang.org/tutorials/language/futures and https://www.dartlang.org/tutorials/language/futures#calling-multiple-funcs in particular

Comment: Even I was considering using `Future.wait` but then `_future2` will always get executed after `_future1`. How can I check the condition and decide accordingly?

Comment: you dont need `Future.wait` you need `expensiveA()
    .then((aValue) => expensiveB())
    .then((bValue) => expensiveC())
    .then((cValue) => doSomethingWith(cValue));` or something like that, more [here](https://www.dartlang.org/tutorials/language/futures#calling-multiple-funcs) or [here](https://www.dartlang.org/tutorials/language/futures#sequential-processing-async)

Comment: Yes I am also trying some more programs like these. Meanwhile - Please add all this in an answer so that I can mark it. :) I wonder why you keep commenting rather than answering.

Comment: you can write a self answer too :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `initState`, I do this -

```
_future1 = func.then(checkCode);
```

And then I wrote another function to decide my widget depending on the code I receive -

```
checkCode(int statusCode) {
if (statusCode == 200) {
  _future2Func();
  widgetToNavigate = Text('');
} else {
  widgetToNavigate = SomeWidget();
}}
```

So finally, my build code looks like this -

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return FutureBuilder(
  future: _future1,
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
    return snapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.done
        ? CircularProgressIndicator()
        : widgetToNavigate;
  },
);}
```

Comment: you are still using two `FutureBuilder`s... - one in `checkCode()` and another in `build()` method

Comment: Only If I receive 200 in the first one. I need to load info and show progress indicator till the info is loaded...Is this wrong?

Comment: use one `FutureBuilder` inside `build()` method which either builds `CircularProgressIndicator` or `YourFinalWidget` when your `Future` completes

Comment: [here](https://flutter-academy.com/async-in-flutter-futurebuilder/) you can read how to deal with errors with `FutureBuilder` - i mean: `if (snapshot.hasError) { ...`

Answer (score 0):

Extract your inner `FutureBuilder` into a separate stateful widget of its own and only call it when the outer condition says so (showing something else, maybe just an empty `Container` otherwise). Then it can have its own internal logic with its own future inside.

This solution works even if the second future comes much later, not directly around the beginning of the page but, for instance, in response to user input.